# PHP 8 - libxml_disable_entity_loader() has been deprecated. How do I replace the functionality it provides?

Tags: php, deprecation-warning

I am upgrading to PHP 8 and getting the following warning:

*Function libxml_disable_entity_loader() is deprecated*

**What I have:** This code saves the current entity loader status, and enables the loader; then loads the file; and finally resets the entity loader to its original status:

```
...
$current = libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
$domdocument->load($filename,$options);
libxml_disable_entity_loader($current);
...
```

I read the following regarding PHP 8:

> as of libxml 2.9.0 entity substitution is disabled by default, so
> there is no need to disable the loading of external entities, unless
> there is the need to resolve internal entity references with
> LIBXML_NOENT.

To test, I removed the libxml_disable_entity_loader() references, thus **What I have:** becomes:

```
...
$domdocument->load($filename,$options);
...
```

However, now of course I get:

*PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity*

So, my question is:

What do I need to do in PHP 8 to get rid of *libxml_disable_entity_loader()* and still achieve the equivalent of **What I have:**

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for all use cases but in mine all loads are from local files, so I have resolved the problem by replacing ->load() with a combination of file_get_contents() and ->loadXML() as follows:

```
...
$domdocument->loadXML(file_get_contents($filename),$options);
...
```

Thus side stepping the "external" consideration.

Answer (score 1):

I have not dug deep into this topic, but I suppressed the warning by adding @ symbol at the beginning of the method and no change has come to the result of the code.
try like below

```
...
$current = @libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
$domdocument->load($filename,$options);
@libxml_disable_entity_loader($current);
...
```

Comment: Hi @nesar - thanks. for now it is a warning as deprecated but it will turn into an error when removed. To deal with this for 8 and above I simply remove the check as follows: 
if PHP_VERSION_ID < 80000) { 
   libxml_disable_entity_loader(...
  ....
}

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (\PHP_VERSION_ID < 80000) {
      libxml_disable_entity_loader(true);
 }
```

https://php.watch/versions/8.0/libxml_disable_entity_loader-deprecation

Comment: Hi - yes, if you see my comment to @nesar above I am dealing with it it this way also. What is the \ for?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to keep support for external entities you can use the mentioned `LIBXML_NOENT` flag to do so. Just add it to `$options` to pass it to `DOMDocument::load()`.

```php
$options = $options | LIBXML_NOENT;
$domdocument->load($filename,$options);
```

As described in [the documentation for `DOMDocument::load()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php), the `$options` parameter is there to pass:

> Bitwise OR of the libxml option constants

Please note that it's not advised to use `LIBXML_NOENT` unless you can absolutely trust the XML source as it opens you up for [XML External Entity (XXE) Processing attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Processing).